# Changing search text with Javascript Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I know this seems simple and obsolete, but I can't find a proper example of this anywhere.

My goal is to edit my search bar by adding text to the beginning of whatever the user inputs with javascript.

For example, a user inputs "Pie", there are three buttons underneath the search bar, the user can select "Apple" "Banana" or "Squash". When clicking on any of the buttons it should add the text to the beginning of pie, e.g. clicking on "Banana" Results in modifying the search bar with "Banana Pie".

I'm just trying to learn how to do this in JS and I can't find a proper example of this anywhere if someone can point me to the proper place to look i would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```js
function SetValue(ts) {
  var txt = document.getElementById("searchabar");
  var n = txt.value.indexOf(":");
  var text = txt.value;
  if (n > 0) {
    var text = txt.value.substring(n + 1);
  }
  txt.value = ts + ":" + text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="" name="" placeholder="Search bar" id="searchabar">
  <input type="button" name="" value='Apple' onclick="SetValue('Apple')">
  <input type="button" name="" value='Squash' onclick="SetValue('Squash')">
  <input type="button" name="" value='Banana' onclick="SetValue('Banana')">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Type something and the click on apple followed by Squash, it seems to add both.

Comment: thanks! 

Is there anyway to make it so that you can't select multiple options, or strip previous button, e.g. if i click apple then squash it adds AppleSquash in the input.

Comment: @ilovejq I didn't get it please explain more

Comment: @ManuVarghese For example, i set it up so it is Apple:Pie, Banana:Pie, Squash:Pie (separated with a `:`). If i click on Banana Twice, it does `Banana:Banana:Pie`, or if i click apple & banana it makes it `Apple:Banana:Pie` how can i prevent this so only one type of pie may be selected?

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for :) thank you so much! @ManuVarghese

Answer (score 0):

If you had an input element:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput">
```

Then you can get the value of it with:

```
let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

In your event handler for the buttons, then you could just do string concatenation:

```
// In your button click event
let outputString = buttonValue + " " + userInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in following steps:

- Create the buttons in the html and give them same class.
- Access them in javascript and add onclick listener to them.
- Change the value of `input` in that function.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('test');

document.querySelectorAll('.fruit').forEach(fruit => {
  fruit.onclick= function(){
    input.value = `${fruit.innerText} ${input.value}`
  }
  
})
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" />
<button class="fruit">Apple</button>
<button class="fruit">Banana</button>
```